# Create multiple hotspots on 1 device

Tags: wifi

How can I create multiple wifi hotspots on 1 device?
I tried this:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=hotspotname key=123456789
```

But I can only create 1 hotspot with that command.
How can I create more?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Hardware of your device, I don't think that it's possible to create more than one WiFi at a time.